# How to prevent plotly chart title from becoming left aligned after figure updates?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plot in my dash app that initially has a title that is centered above the plot. However, once I update the figure the title becomes left aligned. I cannot figure out why this is the case and would like to know how I can prevent the title from shifting itself and instead keep in centered above the plot. Here is the code for my dash app:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api.stats.endpoints.shotchartdetail import ShotChartDetail

court_shapes = []

outer_lines_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-250',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='250',
    y1='422.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(outer_lines_shape)

hoop_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='7.5',
    y0='7.5',
    x1='-7.5',
    y1='-7.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(hoop_shape)

backboard_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-30',
    y0='-7.5',
    x1='30',
    y1='-6.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    ),
    fillcolor='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)'
)

court_shapes.append(backboard_shape)

outer_three_sec_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-80',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='80',
    y1='143.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(outer_three_sec_shape)

inner_three_sec_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-60',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='60',
    y1='143.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(inner_three_sec_shape)

left_line_shape = dict(
    type='line',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-220',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='-220',
    y1='92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(left_line_shape)

right_line_shape = dict(
    type='line',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='220',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='220',
    y1='92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)   

court_shapes.append(right_line_shape)

three_point_arc_shape = dict(
    type='path',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    path='M -220 92.5 C -70 300, 70 300, 220 92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(three_point_arc_shape)

center_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='60',
    y0='482.5',
    x1='-60',
    y1='362.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(center_circle_shape)

res_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='20',
    y0='442.5',
    x1='-20',
    y1='402.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(res_circle_shape)

free_throw_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='60',
    y0='200',
    x1='-60',
    y1='80',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(free_throw_circle_shape)

res_area_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='40',
    y0='40',
    x1='-40',
    y1='-40',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1,
        dash='dot'
    )
)

court_shapes.append(res_area_shape)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='shot-graph',
            figure={
                'layout': go.Layout( 
                    title="test",
                    shapes= court_shapes,
                    height=800,
                    width=1000,
                    xaxis= dict(
                        showgrid=False,
                        range=[-300, 300],
                        showticklabels=False,
                        zeroline=False
                    ),
                    yaxis= dict(
                        showgrid=False,
                        range=[-100, 500],
                        showticklabels=False,
                        zeroline=False
                    )
                )
            },
            config={
                'displayModeBar': False
            }
        ),
    ],style = {'margin': 'auto', 'width': '50%'}), 
    html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='playerName-state', type='text', value='Brook Lopez'),
            dcc.Input(id='season-state', type='text', value='2018-19'),
            html.Button('Submit', id='button')
    ],style = {'margin-left': '675px'})
])

@app.callback(
    Output('shot-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    state=[
        State(component_id='playerName-state', component_property='value'),
        State(component_id='season-state', component_property='value')]
)
def update_figure(n_clicks, playerName, season):
    playerID = players.find_players_by_full_name(str(playerName))[0]['id']
    shotchart_detail = ShotChartDetail(team_id = 0, player_id = playerID, season_nullable= str(season), context_measure_simple= "FGA")
    shotData = shotchart_detail.get_data_frames()[0]
    shotData["LOC_X"] *= -1
    made_shots = shotData.loc[shotData.SHOT_MADE_FLAG == 1]
    missed_shots = shotData.loc[shotData.SHOT_MADE_FLAG == 0]

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=made_shots["LOC_X"], y=made_shots["LOC_Y"], mode='markers', marker_color="BLUE", name="Made Shot"))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=missed_shots["LOC_X"], y=missed_shots["LOC_Y"], mode='markers', marker_color="RED", name="Missed Shot"))

    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Shots by %s in the %s NBA season' % (playerName, season), 
        showlegend=False,
        xaxis=dict(
            showgrid=False,
            range=[-300, 300],
            showticklabels=False,
            zeroline=False
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            showgrid=False,
            range=[-100, 500],
            showticklabels=False,
            zeroline=False
        ),
        height = 800,
        width = 1000,
        shapes=court_shapes,
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    )
    fig.update(layout=layout)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the title is becoming left-aligned (and various other style changes are likely occurring!) is that while your initial figure is defined as straight `dict` objects, your callback returns a `go.Figure` object which uses Plotly's new built-in `template`.

To make `go.Figure` not do this, you can pass in `template=None` to your `go.Layout` constructor.

More documentation here: https://plot.ly/python/templates/